# Revoke privileges on an object a role doesn't own in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions, azure

## Context

I created a fresh Azure Database for Postgres and here is how it looks like at first:

```
postgres> \l
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Name              | Owner           | Encoding   | Collate                    | Ctype                      | Access privileges                   |
|-------------------+-----------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------------|
| azure_maintenance | azure_superuser | UTF8       | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | azure_superuser=CTc/azure_superuser |
| azure_sys         | azure_superuser | UTF8       | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | <null>                              |
| postgres          | azure_superuser | UTF8       | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | <null>                              |
| template0         | azure_superuser | UTF8       | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/azure_superuser                  |
|                   |                 |            |                            |                            | azure_superuser=CTc/azure_superuser |
| template1         | azure_superuser | UTF8       | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/azure_superuser                  |
|                   |                 |            |                            |                            | azure_superuser=CTc/azure_superuser |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------------+

postgres> \dn+
+--------+-----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Name   | Owner           | Access privileges                  | Description            |
|--------+-----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------|
| public | azure_superuser | azure_superuser=UC/azure_superuser | standard public schema |
|        |                 | =UC/azure_superuser                |                        |
+--------+-----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------+

postgres> \du
+---------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| rolname                   | rolsuper   | rolinherit   | rolcreaterole   | rolcreatedb   | rolcanlogin   | rolconnlimit   | rolvaliduntil   | memberof                                                             | rolreplication   |
|---------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------|
| azure_pg_admin            | False      | True         | False           | False         | False         | -1             | <null>          | []                                                                   | True             |
| azure_superuser           | True       | True         | True            | True          | True          | -1             | <null>          | []                                                                   | True             |
| admin                     | False      | True         | True            | True          | True          | -1             | <null>          | ['azure_pg_admin']                                                   | True             |
+---------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

## Action

When connected as user `admin`, I tried to revoke privileges on the public schema that is owned by `azure_superuser` like so:

```
postgres> select current_user, session_user, current_database();
+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
| current_user   | session_user   | current_database   |
|----------------+----------------+--------------------|
| admin          | admin          | postgres           |
+----------------+----------------+--------------------+

postgres> revoke all on schema public from azure_superuser;

postgres> \dn+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
+--------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| Name   | Owner           | Access privileges   | Description            |
|--------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------|
| public | azure_superuser | =UC/azure_superuser | standard public schema |
+--------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------+
```

## Question

How is it possible it works? I thought only the owner of an object could grant and revoke privileges as well as roles with the grant option.

Comment: Perhaps they hacked up PostgreSQL.

Comment: It seems specific to the `admin` account. I did the same with an other user and got this `WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"` as expected.